# How can i add jquery to Appcelerator Titanium Mobile Work?

Tags: jquery, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

Is it possible to integrate the jquery in to Titanium Appcelerator and will it work properly?
Else we can't integrate the jquery in titanium appcelerator?

any one help me?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to do? I'm not sure that it work well without the DOM

Answer (score 1):

> you can use basically any JS library
>   you want in a WebView. Outside of a
>   WebView, you can use basically any JS
>   library that does not require the DOM
>   (like json2.js, etc.)

(from [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121/use-of-jquery))

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following forum. YOu can use Jquery by removing DOM from it
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/121/use-of-jquery

Answer (score 0):

First You should create a htlm file. You should see code details below. There is jquery function. Do not forget upload jquery-1.9.min.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Local URL</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

function firedFromWebView(msg){
    $("div").html(msg);
}

//Notice that jQuery works within WebViews
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("a").click(function(e){
    //This will fire the custom event "fromWeb" and send the second argument
    //as the event's value
        Titanium.App.fireEvent("fromWeb",{value:"Fired from webpage"});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>A Local Webpage</h1>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Touch to Fire Event</a>
    <br/>
    <div>Listening...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And Another update code blocks on app.js

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    title:"App to Web View Interaction Through Events",
    backgroundColor:"#FFFFFF"
});

var webView = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    url:"html/index.html"
});

var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title:"Fire WebView Javascript",
    height:48,
    width:220,
    bottom:12
});

button.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    webView.evalJS("firedFromWebView('<strong>Fired!</strong>')");
});

//We can use a custom event listener to fire native code from Javascript pages
//by using Titanium.App.addEventListener
Titanium.App.addEventListener("fromWeb",function(e){
    //The data structure and value of e is defined in the
    //index.html page
    alert(e.value);
});

win.add(webView);
win.add(button);
win.open();
```