# Titanium Alloy using jquery

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-modules, titanium-alloy

Am new to Titanium Appcelerator and am using Titanium Alloys to develop my Mobile App Module. As I read in Titanium docs, Alloys have built-in support for underscore.js and Backbone.js. Is it possible to use jquery to develop apps with Titanium Alloys?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913679/how-can-i-add-jquery-to-appcelerator-titanium-mobile-work appears you can use it with Titanium.  There is no DOM to manipulate, but you should be able to use the general utility functions as they state in this other question.

Comment: @Martin - Thank you. So I cant use jquery in place of generating apps for android and ios. Is it so?

Comment: It appears you could use it in a WebView situation, but I feel you would be complicating Titanium doing that.  You may be comfortable with jQuery, but trying to conform Titanium to it may frustrate you with developing with Titanium IMO.  I'd suggest trying Titanium the way it is built, using an example application.  Appcelerator really did a decent job in the structuring and ease if creating an app with Alloy.  I'd suggest trying it their way and adjusting as needed.

Comment: Ok Martin. Thank you. Is Underscore.js and Backbone.js is must to use for all its activity? else we can go with pure js?

Comment: With Alloy, Backbone.js is the way the models and controllers are implemented.  I think the views as well, but that may be abstracted away.  Backbone.js depends on Underscore.js, but you don't specifically have to use Underscore.js beyond what Titanium is doing in the background.  You can use pure js and pretty much any library that doesn't specialize in manipulating the DOM.

Comment: What kind of module do you want to create ?

Answer (score 0):

Practically no, but technically yes.

No, you can't use it in the bulk of your Titanium code because jQuery requires a DOM and Titanium does not create web-based apps, so there is not DOM. That's why DOM-less helpers like underscore.js are encouraged. That said...

Yes, you can use jQuery *inside a Ti.UI.WebView* in Titanium. As the webviews indeed have a DOM, they can be used in the web-based code contained in the webview.